# Xampp portable on USB stick - configure xdebug

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I did install xampp portable server on USB stick by downloading the zip version from https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/1.8.3/
(out of the question's context I want to tell you that first I tried to install it via the installer but was working only on the PC, which the installation was made, so if you install it I suggest you do it like extracting it from the zip file, so it will work on every PC you plug in the flash drive).

So I have NetBeans 8 which I successfully use to debug PHP when I use the locally installed WAMP server.

I'm trying to debug PHP code that is on the portable XAMPP server but I fail.

php.ini xdebug configuration looks like this:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
xdebug.idekey = netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "\xampp\tmp\xdebug"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_log = "\xampp\tmp\xdebug\xdebug_remot.log"
xdebug.show_local_vars = 9
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "\xampp\tmp\xdebug"
```

If someone did this and is this kind to tell me how to do it, it is going to be great.

Thanks

Comment: And "but I fail" means what _exactly_?

Comment: This means that I am not able to debug the code through NetBeans(NB) and seems that NB is not able to connect to xdebug. I see in the bottom right of NB undetermined progress bar with text "Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will share what exactly the problem was.

First I check the result of `phpinfo()` and I realize that **xdebug** module is not loaded at all, but the path to the extension was looking pretty right.

Then I changed `zend_extension = "\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"` to `zend_extension=php_xdebug.dll` and then I was able to debug PHP application hosted on this XAMPP portable server with NetBeans.

Cheers!

Comment: Saved. My. Day. Thanks.